# difference with import for simple piece

Tags: python

Filee.py

```
a = 5
i = 6

def f(x):
    print(x*x)
```

```
from Filee import *
```

then I can call `f(a)`

```
import Filee
```

then I need to call `Filee.f(Filee.a)`

How are the two import different?

Comment: You just described the difference. What are you confused about?

Comment: What do you mean? Were you expecting something different to happen? If you need to learn about importing, maybe check out [this section of the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) (6 and 6.1).

Comment: not to be rude, but the difference is that that is how it is made to work. If you `import * `then you don't need the library/module name, and if you don't then you need it. The more real indepth of why is in the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be for convenience. If you use `import Filee` to import `Filee.f` into your namespace, then you need to type out `Filee.f` every single time you want to use the function f.

However, if you also have a function `f` in your current namespace and you also want to use the function f from Filee.f, then you might want to use Filee.f to call it so that you're not overwriting your function f (as python doesn't support function overloading). For example:

```
import Filee

def f(x):
    return x

x = f(2)
y = Filee.f(x)
```

Here it is useful to have the library/module name to avoid overloading the function f. Also, it's best to import only the functions you need from a module. `from Filee import *` is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

`from Filee import *` means from `Filee` import everything. By default, I don't like this approach unless you are aware what you are importing. That is because you are on risk of having two different function from two different library but with same name. In your case, other `Filee2.py` might contain function `f` with completely different code.

In the other hand, `import Filee` force you to use `Filee.f`, so if there is `Filee2.f`, you can use both separately.

Answer (score -1):

`from Filee import *` will import everything from that module into the current, so you can directly call the function `f(a)`

If you import as `import Filee` you'll need to prefix the module name.

Don't exclusively use the first import case, as it can be very inefficient for some modules